# Show Only One Row (the Latest) in a Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just cannot get my head around this one. I need the below query to show me only the latest backup per database, regardless of the fact if it is differential or full.

In my case, the query renders two rows for a specific database - one for the latest differential and one for the latest full.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
SELECT A.server_name as Instance, B.name as Database_Name,
       ISNULL(Convert(char(19), max(backup_finish_date), 100), 'NEVER') as Backup_Date, case when type='D' then 'FULL' when type='I' then 'DIFFERENTIAL'when type='L' then 'LOG'end  as Backup_Type,
       'Succeeded' as Status
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases B LEFT OUTER JOIN
     msdb.dbo.backupset A
     ON A.database_name = B.name
where B.name not in ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb') and
      a.machine_name IS NOT NULL and type in ('D', 'I')
GROUP BY B.name, A.machine_name, A.server_name, A.type
ORDER BY B.name, Backup_Date desc, A.type;
```

Comment: Select top(1) ...

Comment: because you have added `group by a.type` it will show one row for each type..

Comment: Nenand, I must have a.type in the GROUP BY as otherwise it throws "Column msdb.dbo.backupset is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause". But thank you for shedding light on why I see one row for FULL and one row for DIFFERENTIAL - it makes full sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use row_number filter by 1 as below:

```
Select * from (
    SELECT A.server_name as Instance, B.name as Database_Name,
           ISNULL(Convert(char(19), max(backup_finish_date), 100), 'NEVER') as Backup_Date, case when type='D' then 'FULL' when type='I' then 'DIFFERENTIAL'when type='L' then 'LOG'end  as Backup_Type,
           'Succeeded' as Status,
           RowN = Row_Number() over(Partition by B.name, A.machine_name, A.server_name, A.type order by backup_finish_date desc)
    FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases B LEFT OUTER JOIN
         msdb.dbo.backupset A
         ON A.database_name = B.name
    where B.name not in ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb') and
          a.machine_name IS NOT NULL and type in ('D', 'I')
) sq 
Where sq.RowN = 1
ORDER BY sq.name, sq.Backup_Date desc, sq.type
```

Comment: if you are using row_number(), there is no longer need for group by, is it?

Comment: Hello Kannan, this worked. I just had to add to add A.backup_finish_date in the GROUP BY otherwise the SQL Server engine was complaining and also use the aliases in the ORDER BY for sq.name (sq.Database_Name) and sq.type (sq.Backup_Type). Thank you.

Comment: You do not require group by as we are handling that in partition by column in RowN calculation.